# New dropdown appears when dropdown item selected

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I want new dropdown menus to appear when Country or County is clicked and disappear if one of the other two options are selected.

```
<select name="location">
    <option value="country">Country</option>
    <option value="county">County</option>
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
    <option value="ROI">ROI</option>
    <option value="worldwide">Worldwide</option>
</select>
```

Comment: just to be clear. do you want a whole new select box or new options to appear within this select box?  Also where is the data coming from for  the new box/options?

Answer (score 0):

You can just `hide` the new dropdown and `show` it when selected the `Country` or County`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#new').hide();
    $('#location').change(function() {
         var selected =   $(this).find(":selected").text();
        console.log(selected);
        if(selected == 'Country' || selected == 'County'){
            $('#new').toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

[JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HM5sL/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
// Initial state of newdropdown
var locationVal = $("#location").val();

if ((locationVal === 'country') || (locationVal === 'county')) {
    $("#newdropdown").show();
} else {
    $("#newdropdown").hide();
}

// location drop down change event callback
$("#location").change(function () {
    if (($(this).val() === 'country') || ($(this).val() === 'county')) {
        $("#newdropdown").show();
    } else {
        $("#newdropdown").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I assumed you already have newdropdown (which we are toggling). Do you want to create this dropdown dynamically? Please provide more information (clear and concise, please).